# Images are not coming in PDF, using ITextRenderer

Tags: java, html, xslt, itext

Am trying to convert my html content into PDF. Am having some text as well as images (PNG) in my html document. After converting using `iTextRenderer` only images are not coming in PDF, rest of the text contents are coming properly. Am printing my html content too (using Sysout) image tag is coming properly but not displaying in PDF.

Please find my java code below.

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
Document resultDoc = (Document) result.getNode();
renderer.setDocument(resultDoc, "");
renderer.layout();


ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
renderer.createPDF(baos);
baos.close();
return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: You tag this question as an iText question, but `ITextRenderer` is not an iText question. It's a Flying Saucer class, hence this should be tagged as a Flying Saucer question. Flying Saucer is a product that uses an old version of iText, and that is not endorsed by iText Group. If you want to convert HTML to PDF, you should use iText 7 + pdfHTML as described in the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml).

Comment: Why 'should'???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by changing the dependencies. Earlier i was using the following dependencies which is not parsing image into PDF file.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xhtmlrenderer/core-renderer -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId> 
    <version>R8pre2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then i replaced it with the below dependencies and its worked fine. No code change required.

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-itext5</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.13</version>
    </dependency>
```